# How to add a compiler option to every port being built?

Tags: vcpkg

Is there a way to add a compiler option to every vcpkg port being built?

In particular I need every port to be compiled with `-fdata-section -ffunction-section -flto` in my Linux vcpkg instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to "isanych" (see [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/7309#issuecomment-513795012)):

You can use VCPKG_C_FLAGS* VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS* VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS* variables in you custom triplet files. Here how I do lto on linux:

```
set(VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE -flto)
set(VCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE -flto)
set(VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE -flto)
```

and on windows:

```
set(VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/GL /Gw /GS-")
set(VCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/GL /Gw /GS-")
set(VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/OPT:ICF=3 /LTCG")
```

There is an issue [#7159](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/7159) with multiple flags in boost, with fix [#7160](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/7160).

Note: as of now `VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` isn't being used particularly wide amongst ports.

Comment: Just a note: values from these end up being appended to `CMAKE_*_FLAGS_INIT` variables by a corresponding vcpkg toolchain file (*if that toolchain does so*), which are then used [by CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_INIT.html) to set `CMAKE_*_FLAGS`. And also this works [only](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/d8e60ef4741584f2957788ed0786dd365c92c4d9/docs/users/triplets.md#vcpkg_cxx_flags) if one does not use `VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, in which case I guess that chainloaded toolchain would need to be modified to set `CMAKE_*_FLAGS_INIT`.